@MockBean Not Injecting Dependencies Correctly in Spring Boot Unit Test
I am working on a unit test for a Spring Boot application. I have a MetricsLogger DI that work fine in the service code, but failed to pass the unit test as it's null in the test. Despite using @MockBean, the injected dependency (MetricsLogger) is still null and give me NPE. I'm not sure how to handle the DI when initializing the Repository in unit test. Thank you for any suggestion!
Here is the service code
public class Repository {
  private final DynamoDbTable<Record> table;
  @Qualifier("RepositoryMetricsLogger")
  @Autowired
  private MetricsLogger metricsLogger;

  public Repository(DynamoDbEnhancedClient client, String tableName) {
    this.table = client.table(tableName, TableSchema.fromClass(Record.class));
  }
}

Here is the MetricLog Config
@Data
@Component
public class MetricConfig {

    @Bean("RepositoryMetricsLogger")
    public MetricsLogger repositoryMetricsLogger() {
        return Metrics.getMetricsLogger("Repository"); 
    }

Here is the tester code
@ExtendWith(SpringExtension.class)
public class RepositoryTest {
  private static final DynamoTableLocalFixture ddbLocal =
      new DynamoTableLocalFixture();

  private Repository repository;

  @MockBean
  private MetricsLogger metricsLogger;
  @BeforeEach
  public void setup() {
    MockitoAnnotations.openMocks(this);
    ddbLocal.createTable();
    DynamoDbEnhancedClient ddbLocalEnhancedClient = DynamoDbEnhancedClient.builder()
        .dynamoDbClient(ddbLocal.getDynamoDBClient())
        .build();

    repository = new Repository(ddbLocalEnhancedClient, ddbLocal.getTableName());
  }


And why shouldn't it be null? You are n't using Spring in your test to create the Repository but do it yourself. So how should Spring inject anything?

Why do you invoke MockitoAnnotations.openMocks(this); when you don't have any Mockito annotations in your file? Why do you expect new Repository(...) to get some of its fields magically injected? Why do you mix constructor and field-based dependency injection?

confused usage in your code  snippet , just pick one way to DI  , not mix them all

Perhaps you should consider to make a @SpringBootTest with a local dynamodb if you want to rely on @MockBean and Spring injection.
